# Tor Browser with Flash AND firewall software

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, firefox, flash

Tor Browser developers have often stated that using Flash Player with Tor Browser isn't considered safe because Flash can connect to the Internet on its own bypassing the Tor Browser.

My question is would using a firewall software such as Comodo Firewall to prevent Flash from making its own connections solve this problem? If so are there any other pitfalls with using Flash (other than the vulnerabilities that are present when using "normal" browsers)?

Comment: I feel there is no real answer to your question, because there are so many pitfalls and unknowns.

Also - how can you be sure that the firewall will block it properly?
If I was to use it then I'd try to get the open source flash plugins to run in either tails or whonix, that way there is a extra layer of protection in the transparent proxying.

Comment: Comodo was sighted in [privacy violations](http://www.infoworld.com/article/2623829/authentication/weaknesses-in-ssl-certification-exposed-by-comodo-security-breach.html) as far as I know. No sane person will beleive that certs were actually *just stolen*. Imagine the quality+purpose of their other tools...

Answer (score 3):

There are many more issues with Flash. It can create persistent "cookies" that Tor Browser has no control over, for example. This is why just adding a firewall would *not* make inclusion of Flash safe.